# Tokenising whitespace in a half-whitespace sensitive language?

Tags: parsing

I have made some searches, including taking a second look through the red Dragon Book in front of me, but I haven't found a clear answer to this. Most people are talking about whitespace-sensitivity in terms of *indentation*, but that's not my case.

I want to implement a transpiler for a simple language. This language has a concept of a "command", which is a reserved keyword followed by some arguments. To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, a sequence of commands may look something like this:

```
print "hello, world!";
set running 1;
while running @
    read progname;
    launch progname;
    print "continue? 1 = yes, 0 = no";
    readint running;
@
```

Informally, you can view the grammar as something along the lines of

```
<program>    ::= <statement> <program>
<statement>  ::= while <expression> <sequence>
              |  <command> ;
<sequence>   ::= @ <program> @
              |  <statement>
<command>    ::= print <expression>
              |  set <variable> <expression>
              |  read <variable>
              |  readint <variable>
              |  launch <expression>
<expression> ::= <variable>
              |  <string>
              |  <int>
```

for simplicity, we can define the following as such

```
<string> is an arbitrary sequence of characters surrounded by quotes
<int> is a sequence of characters '0'..'9'
<variable> is a sequence of characters 'a'..'z'
```

Now this would ordinarily not be any problem. In fact, given just this specification I have a working implementation, where the lexer silently eats all whitespace. However, here's the catch:

> **Arguments to commands must be separated by whitespace!**

In other words, it should be illegal to write

```
while running@print"hello";@
```

even though this clearly isn't ambiguous as far as the grammar is concerned. I have had two ideas on how to solve this.

1. Output a token whenever some whitespace is consumed, and include whitespace in the grammar. I suspect this will make the grammar a lot more complicated.
2. Rewrite the grammar so instead of "hard-coding" the arguments of each command, I have a production rule for "arguments" taking care of whitespace. It may look something like

   ```
   <command>   ::= <cmdtype> <arguments>
   <arguments> ::= <argument> <arguments>
   <argument>  ::= <expression>
   <cmdtype>   ::= print | set | read | readint | launch
   ```

   Then we can make sure the lexer somehow (?) takes care of leading whitespace whenever it encounters an `<argument>` token. However, this moves the complexity of dealing with the arity (among other things?) of built-in commands into the parser.

How is this normally solved? **When the grammar of a language requires whitespace in particular places but leaves it optional almost everywhere else, does it make sense to deal with it in the lexer or in the parser?**

I wish I could fudge the specification of the language just a teeny tiny bit because that would make it much simpler to implement, but unfortunately this is a backward-compatibility issue and not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards compatibility is usually taken to apply only to correct programs; accepting a program which previously would have benn rejected as a syntax error cannot alter the behaviour of any valid program and thus does not violate backwards compatibility.

That might not be relevant in this case, but since it would, as you note, simplify the problem considerably, it seemed worth mentioning.

One solution is to pass whitespace on to the parser, and then incorporate it into the grammar; normally, you would define a terminal, `WS`, and from that a non-terminal for optional whitespace:

```
<ows> ::= WS |
```

If you are careful to ensure that only one of the terminal and the non-terminal are valid in any context, this does not affect parsability, and the resulting grammar, while a bit cluttered, is still readable. The advantage is that it makes the whitespace rules explicit.

Another option is to handle the issue in the lexer; that might be simple but it depends on the precise nature of the language.

From your description, it appears that the goal is to produce a syntax error if two tokens are not separated by whitespace, unless one of the tokens is "self-delimiting"; in the example shown, I believe the only such token is the semicolon, since you seem to indicate that `@` must be whitespace-delimited. (It could be that your complete language has more self-delimiting tokens, but that does not substantially alter the problem.)

That can be handled with a single start condition in the lexer (assuming you are using a lexer generator which allows explicit states); reading whitespace puts you in a state in which any token is valid (which is the initial state, `INITIAL` if you are using a lex-derivative). In the other state, only self-delimiting tokens are valid. The state after reading a token will be the restricted state unless the token is self-delimiting.

This requires pretty well every lexer action to include a state transition action, but leaves the grammar unaltered. The effect is to move the clutter from the parser to the scanner, at the cost of obscuring the whitespace rules. But it might be less clutter and it will certainly simplify a future transition to a whitespace-agnostic dialect, if that is in your plans.

There is a different scenario, which is a posix-like shell in which identifiers (called "words" in the shell grammar) are not limited to alphabetic characters, but might include any non-self-delimiting character. In a posix shell, `print"hello, world"` is a single word, distinct from the two token sequence `print "hello, world"`. (The first one will eventually be dequoted into the single token `printhello, world`.)

That scenario can really only be handled lexically, although it is not necessarily complicated. It might be a guide to your problem as well; for example, you could add a lexical rule which accepts any string of characters other than whitespace and self-delimiting characters; the maximal munch rule will ensure that action is only taken if the token cannot be recognised as an identifier or a string (or other valid tokens), so you can just throw an error in the action.

That is even simpler than the state-based lexer, but it is somewhat less flexible.

Comment: My worry is that by including whitespace in the parser/grammar, almost all productions will turn out to look something like `<a> ::= <ows> <b> <ows> <c> <ows>` where "cluttered" is somewhat of an understatement. However, your idea of having two states in the lexer to deal with only allowing self-delimiting tokens in certain cases is fantastic. I think I'll go that way, and it's much cleaner than whatever I had in mind before. I love it when I ask a somewhat niche question and someone like you show the absolute best sides of Stack Overflow. Massive thanks!!

Comment: @kqr:  If your rule was that operands had to be seperated by commas, you grammar would have an explicit comma operand where you are writing <b>.  I assume you are OK with the grammar rule with the commas; why is the whitespace version different?   Would  you try to hack the lexer to supress the "comma"?   When you state that a "something" must be present, the right thing to do in the grammar is express its presence explicility.  That's the point of the grammar: to make to clear to the reader (and tools) what precisely is necessary.

Comment: @IraBaxter The difference is pehaps subtle: spaces are optional almost everywhere, so if I include spaces in the grammar, I have to also include "optional spaces" around almost every single production in the grammar. Commas generally aren't optional anywhere, so including them in the grammar can be done only at the point where they are required.

Comment: @kqr, the grammar rules are more likely ti have the form `<a> ::= <b> <ows> <c>`, since any use of `<a>` will be in some context with a whitespace annotation. You must avoid the possibility of two consecutive whitespace markers; it's ambiguous if they are optional and unfulfillable otherwise.